# UITableView get smaller

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I will try to explain my problem with the help of pictures :

Firstly, I just added an UITableView to my UIViewController. I selected it to show its frame and there was no problem.
[image]
Next, when I connect my button to my UIViewController, my UITableView gets smaller. 
I selected it to see that the frame doesn't match with the contents. I noticed that the tableview reduces exactly of 64 (44 from the UINavigationBar + 20 from the bar with the battery)
[image]

At the beginning, I thought it was juste a display problem from XCode, but next when I tried to run it with cells, the problem still exist.

So I put a UIContainerView in my UIViewController and my tableView in the controller of the container. XCode display properly my table view, but when in run it, I get the same problem.

[image]

Thank you in advance,
Sorry for my english.

Comment: When you connect the two controllers using a the segue, xCode show the navigation bar on the second view controller because the first one, the one that it is making the segue, is inside a navigation controller.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why my tableview get smaller

Comment: if you set the width and height using constraints it should stay the same.

Comment: Actually that doesn't change anything, because as you can see on the second picture, the frame of the UITableView a still the same size, but it is just the content of the tableview that gets smaller. The grey part should fill the whole frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your containing view controller's Adjust Scroll View Insets is checked (in its Attributes inspector). Uncheck it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to explicitly set the size of your cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
}
```